# AngulerJSでのモーダル画面表示

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

AngulerJSとBootStrapを使用してモーダル画面を表示しようとしているのですが
`$modal.open`のところで

```
TypeError Cannot read property 'open' undifined
```

とエラーが出てしまいます。
原因はなんでしょうか？

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap']);

//ApplicationController
app.controller("controller", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, $modal)
{
    $scope.AnkenCheck = function(){
        $scope.newGuest = {};
        $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: "AnkenSerch",
                    scope: $scope
                    }); }
}]);
```

Comment: コード部分を選択して`{}`ボタンを押下するとコードをハイライトできます。ご活用ください。

Answer (score 1):

全体的に$modalではなく$uimodalでした
また最初に

```
app.controller("controller", ['$scope', '$http','$uibModal', function($scope, $http, $uibModal )
```

と定義しておいく必要があることがわかりました。
実際につかうときは

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                        templateUrl: "AnkenSerch",
                        scope: $scope
                    });
```

としました